# Play Framework 2.3 on OpenShift database token substitution not working

Tags: openshift, playframework-2.3

I am trying to deploy a Play Framework 2.3 application to OpenShift.

I am following this example: https://github.com/JamesSullivan/play2-openshift-quickstart

Building and deploying the application is working (by that I mean the `push` to the git repository is working and the build is completing successfully), but during startup I see this error in `play.log`:

```
AbstractConnectionHook -
Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. 
Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.
Message:No suitable driver found for jdbc:${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL}
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:272)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:244)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL}
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240)
    ... 18 more
```

So it looks like the ${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL} environment variable token-substitution is not working.

If I log in to my application, I see this via `env` (obviously I replaced the username, password, IP and port for the purposes of posting here):

```
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL=postgresql://xxxx:yyyy@ip:port
```

I have also tried using the other environment variables, like `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST` but those too do not get substituted.

The relevant part of my `openshift.conf` looks like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL}"
db.default.user=myappuser
db.default.password=myapppassword
```

From the linked quickstart project, the following command is used to start the Play server (again, I replaced server-ip for the purposes of this post):

```
/app-root/runtime/repo/target/universal/stage/bin/myapp
"-DapplyEvolutions.default=true" 
-Dhttp.port=8080 -Dhttp.address=server-ip 
-Dconfig.resource=openshift.conf
```

You can see the `openshift.conf` file being referenced.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1.)  Did you install the postgresql cartridge on your gear?  SSH into your gear and run 'env | grep POSTGRESQL' and see if it shows you any of the environment variables.  2.)  Post an issue on that github repo and see what they have to say, since they created it they would be the best to answer questions about it.

Comment: 1) Yes, postgresql cartridge is installed, my db schema is deployed and I can use pgadmin or psql on my on PC to see it; I did mention in my question already that I checked the environment variable was set; 2) Yes, probably that is the way to go. I wasn't sure if it was more of general issue wrt token substitution on Play/OpenShift or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of things, eventually I found something that worked:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://"${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST}":"${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT}/mydb
db.default.user=(((db-user)))
db.default.password=(((dp-password)))
```

The upshot is, it seems, you need to watch out very carefully for correct usage of the quotation characters.

It looks "wrong" (at first glance) since the last quotation character closes the string *prior* to the `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT` variable.